# How could i delete the list from todo app which i want to delete?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have created a todo list app, it runs prefectly, but there's only one issue, like i created two list and I want to remove the second list, when I click on the remove button of second list it removes me the first list not the second list.

Here is my code, could someone please help me, Thanks in advance.

script.js

```
function getAndUpdate() {
  console.log("Updating List...");
  tit = document.getElementById('title').value;

  if (localStorage.getItem('itemsJson') == null) {
    itemJsonArray = [];
    itemJsonArray.push([tit]);
    localStorage.setItem('itemsJson', JSON.stringify(itemJsonArray))


  }
  else {
    itemJsonArrayStr = localStorage.getItem('itemsJson')
    itemJsonArray = JSON.parse(itemJsonArrayStr);
    itemJsonArray.push([tit]);
    localStorage.setItem('itemsJson', JSON.stringify(itemJsonArray))
  }
  update();


}

function update() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('itemsJson') == null) {
    itemJsonArray = [];
    localStorage.setItem('itemsJson', JSON.stringify(itemJsonArray))
  }
  else {
    itemJsonArrayStr = localStorage.getItem('itemsJson')
    itemJsonArray = JSON.parse(itemJsonArrayStr);
  }



  // Populate the table
  let tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");
  let str = "";
  itemJsonArray.forEach((element, index) => {
    str += `
      <tr>
      <th scope="row">${index + 1}</th>
      <td class ="ele">${element[0]}</td> 

      <td class="table-buttons" id="spaning-buttons">   
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary open-modal" id = "open" value="click" onclick = "ShowPopUp()">
      <i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><span>Open</span></td>
      
      <td class="table-buttons" id="margin-padding"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary delete-btn" onclick="removeItem()"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><span>Delete</span></td>
      </tr>`;

  });
  tableBody.innerHTML = str;

}

add = document.getElementById("add");
add.addEventListener("click", getAndUpdate);
update();

function removeItem(itemIndex) {
  if (confirm("Do you want to delete?")) {
    console.log("Delete", itemIndex);
    itemJsonArrayStr = localStorage.getItem('itemsJson')
    itemJsonArray = JSON.parse(itemJsonArrayStr);
    // Delete itemIndex element from the array
    itemJsonArray.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('itemsJson', JSON.stringify(itemJsonArray));

    // RemoveLsItem();
    update();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a code snippet?

Comment: Localstorage.removeItem() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the problem is that you forgot to pass the element **index** to the
`removeItem` method

```
  <td class="table-buttons" id="margin-padding"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary delete-btn" onclick="removeItem(${index})"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><span>Delete</span></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var i = 1;

function ADDdata () {
        var text = $('#txtName').val();
        $('#list').append('<ol class="Editdata"></br><span>'+ text + ' </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" id="edit' + i + '" value="Edit">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + '<input type="submit" class="done" id="delete' + i + '" value="Delete"></ol>');
  
$('#edit' + i).click(function(){
    $(this).prev().attr('contenteditable','true');
    $(this).prev().focus();
});

$('#delete' + i).click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});

  i++;
};

$(function() {
    $('#add').on('click', ADDdata);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Todo List</h1>  
    <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Enter Name">
    <input type="submit" id="add" value="Add">
    <p>
        <ul id="list">
        </ul>
    </p>
```